# Auto attacking on collision

Tags: unity-game-engine

For a sidescrolling game I need to attack the enemies which collides with my player range, here is how I do :

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll) {
        Enemy target = coll.gameObject.GetComponent <Enemy> ();
        if (target != null) {
            moving = false;
            anim.SetBool ("attack", true);
            target.Damage (damageValue);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that i deal `damageValue` damages at each frame, so I wanted to add a cooldown, like this:

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll) {
        Enemy target = coll.gameObject.GetComponent <Enemy> ();
        if (target != null && time.time > nextFire) {
            moving = false;
            anim.SetBool ("attack", true);
            target.Damage (damageValue);
            nextFire = Time.time + 1;//I set the cooldown to 1 second
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the player is attacking one time, and never again, I tried to Debug.Log(Time.time) at the end of OnCollisionStay method, and the debug spam is stopping just before the time where Time.time > nextFire;

I tried to Debug.Log at the start of the method, and it seems like OnCollisionStay is not called anymore after this debug freeze, which occurs around 1s - time.deltaTime after the first attack.

So I don't know how to do, basically here it is a 1D side-scrolling, you can just go from right to left, this should be really simple but I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to create a fire rate for the weapon so it is changeable to one bullet at a time or serial fire. You will have control over it. Also prefer raycasting instead of collision. There is a 2D platformer tutorials around but I very liked the one from Brackeys.

[YouTube Playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPV2KyIb3jR42oVBU6K2DIL6Y22Ry9J1c)